# Is there a word for square lattice in 2D, cubic lattice in 3D, and so on?

Tags: integer-lattices, simplex

A [simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex) is a generalization of the notion of a triangle or tetrahedron to arbitrary dimensions. So, and correct me if I'm wrong, you can say a simplex [integer lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(group)) is a generalization of a lattice built from the end points of simplexes in arbitrary dimensions.

But what about the geometric shape square in 2D and cube in 3D? Is there a word for generalizing them in arbitrary dimensions? What if you use them in a lattice? Simpletic honeycomb comes to mind, but obviously doesn't fit.

Comment: The word you are looking for is hypercube (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube)

Comment: @parsiad So it is! Thank you.